# Creating a social media icon

Tags: html, css

I've created my own social media icon like so:

```
<a  href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.org" 
target="_blank"><div 
class="containercross">
<div class="cross1">
<div class="cross2"></div>
</div>
</div></a>
```

Css:

```
.cross1 {height:30px; 
width: 7px; background- 
color: black; margin-left: 
50px;} 
.cross2 {height:30px; 
width: 7px; background- 
color: black; margin-left:  
50px;transform:ro
tate(90deg);margin- 
left:0px;}
```

My question is whether `u=example.org` from the code above will display `example.org` when sharing or my site name? Otherwise how would it know what my site name was?

Comment: You could just have posted `<a  href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.org" target="_blank">Share</a>` without all the other stuff in a [mcve]

Comment: I don’t get what the actual question is supposed to be here.

Comment: And what is the weird link you had at the end. Smells like backlink spam to me

Comment: @Cbroe when you share a link to Facebook it should list your site address as well as a visual rendering. Will it do that with the code above?

Comment: Why are you asking us, instead of simply testing it yourself?

Comment: Try `<a  href="#" onclick="this.href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook uses the `u` parameter to know which site to link to, then pulls the displayed information from metadata elements present in that site's `head` section, such as `title` and various opengraph `meta` elements.

See [this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/essential-meta-tags-social-media/) for more info. Examples they give include:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="European Travel Destinations">
<meta property="og:description" content="Offering tour packages for individuals or groups.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/thumbnail.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/index.htm">
```

Comment: Thanks. So even though it doesn't mention my site title above, amd my site name is not `example.org` it will know which site has directed it there and list that site?

Comment: Nope. You need to change the `u` parameter to your own site. The `Referer` header isn't used (at least not for pulling the information, anyway, though I'm sure Facebook tracks it given how much they love collecting data).